# How can I increase the size of the Google Maps cache?

Tags: google-maps

Currently the size of the Google Maps cache on Android is very small in comparison to the IPhone Maps application. A bigger cache would improve the maps application significantly by helping the maps appear a lot quicker than they do now.

There is an issue raised on Google Code with some further details [(link)](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4471) but wanted to raise it here just in case anyone knows a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The [Brut Mod](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=630887) can cache map tiles on SD card. So you get large cache. 
Caching feature is by default disabled, you need to turn it on in setting.